# how to troubleshoot cordova app suddenly crashing?

Tags: android, cordova, crash

I deployed my latest app to the Android Playstore last week and have not made any changes to my dev environment or to my code.  I sat down today to deploy the debug version to my test phones and without reason when deploying my app to a test device, it compiles and "launches" just fine - but then the app immediately crashes with an error message "Unfortunately, APP has stopped".  Between last app deployment to store and today I have done zero changes.

How in the world can I troubleshoot this?  It places the app icon on the phone and soon as I tap the icon to launch it it gives this error...no splash screen, nothing.  Tap icon, instant error.

The compiled version on the store is working just fine. Though I didn't make any changes, something has to have happened to the code or my test environment, but how can I debug this?   I have never seen a crash like this before - and again, I made no edits, added no plugins...nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use adb logcat. It logs all the system output as well as the exceptions thrown by your app.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: Yes, you need adb logcat in this use case. You can remove all the precedents log with this command adb logcat -b all -c. Then relaunch your app. You can use grep too, because logcat is very verbose.